# Strange automatic transaction after receiving ether

Tags: transactions, ether

I created 2 wallets from my geth node for test how send transactions works, and sent some gwei to the first one from binance. I wanted to transfer ether from the first wallet to the second. I checked normal fee for transactions and set it to 16 gwei. Before sending I unlock my sender wallet. Here is a transaction command:

```
personal.sendTransaction({ from: "0x26b9551dd8f0c92311daa43143ec44e10953ecb3", to: "0x35264245dcbf92937d33231a3717240bec0b69c9", maxFeePerGas: "0x3B9ACA000", maxPriorityFeePerGas: "0x3B9ACA000", value: "0x90F81C5F84000" })
```

Transaction itself: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb18fdbfb9f91f142e86fbe298655efda6d72cb2a8181073f5bc7f9043534df0c

After sending I checked my balance and there was 0. I open my receiver wallet in the etherscan and noticed additional 2 transactions from my receiver wallet. The first was on the next block, the last not included in a block.

First transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9b84d4a7eb3df3702e69c32532de8a6cc68d39ae9cef6cd313f19b1b22d2b4c7

Second transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb66a1c6bc1221a251b81672d5aad90e7fb42ae8734ad055800d0ab67cdeb44e8

I didn't start this transactions, and didn't sign any smart contract before. I don’t understand why all sent coins were automatically sent to an unknown address after receiving. Maybe there are some mechanisms that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not the only one who automatically sends money to this address. It looks like some kind of scam. Only I did not understand how it happened - someone hacked my node? It is not available via http (only pipe), and it does not work with my another account. Stole a private key with a password? I doubt it, I came up with them out of my head and immediately wrote them down in the geth. Before that, did he accidentally generate the same private key with the same password, and put a smart contract on it? It's all very strange how he did it. I don't seem to figure it out and I'll have to create another account...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you used geth to create test wallets, and sent real ether to them.

If that's the case, it's not a scam - if you are generating test wallets on a local node, the mnemonic phrase is public and there are undoubtedly bots in place that will utilise the fact that your private keys are publicly known to syphon ether if anyone decides to send real value to any of the addresses.

Comment: How can a mnemonic phrase be public? Is she recording somewhere? I thought after creating an account (I created it via importRawKey command), the geth gets rid of this information and does not write it down anywhere. Except to the file system in the form of a keystore

Comment: If you generated wallets via, say, hardhat or ganache, the same mnemonic is used and is therefore public. If you send ether from a real wallet to a `localhost` test wallet, your funds will be lost forever.

Comment: But I didn't use any external instrument for generating private key. I made up a word, and encrypt it by sha256 and immediately copied it to the console. I don't understand where the leak could be

Comment: Generally speaking the client generates the private key. Can you explain how you generated your wallets?

Comment: How i wrote above, my private key - encrypted by sha256 an english word. Maybe it is not so secure method for generating private keys :)